# Unresolved reference "Searcher"

Tags: android, algolia

Trying to integrate instant search in my Android app, but "Searcher" is unresolved.
I have the following dependencies currently, am I missing any?

```
implementation "com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.27.0"
implementation "com.algolia:algoliasearch-client-kotlin-jvm:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx:1.15.2'
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.2.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

include core dependency also

implementation 'com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx-core:1.15.2'

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of `instantsearch-androidx` is lacking its transitive dependencies. The [issue was reported on GitHub](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android/issues/159), you can follow its progress there - likely a new version will soon be released with the appropriate dependencies packaged.

As a workaround, you can add the dependencies yourself to your application - depending on the InstantSearch features you use, you might need some or all of the following:

```
implementation "com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx:$VERSION_INSTANTSEARCH"
implementation "com.algolia:instantsearch-androidx-core:$VERSION_INSTANTSEARCH"
implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.27.0'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```